# Error When Accessing plsql function: invalid name pattern

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I have a function which returns array and I am calling this function from java to get the values.

PL/SQL Code

```
create or replace type dates
       is array(10000) of varchar2(32)
```

function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function datefunc (    
    id1    IN number,
    id2    IN NUMBER    

)
    RETURN dates
AS
    datearray          dates;
    sdate       VARCHAR2 (32);
    edate       VARCHAR2 (32);
BEGIN
```

Java code

```
     connection = datacon.getConnection();
                    callablestatement = 
    connection.prepareCall("begin ? :=datefunc(?,?,?); end;");
                    callablestatement.registerOutParameter
(1, OracleTypes.ARRAY,"dates");
                    callablestatement.setInt(2, param1);
                    callablestatement.setInt(3, param2);
                    callablestatement.execute();
```

But when I execute my code I am getting

```
java.sql.SQLException: invalid name pattern: schema.dates
```

What could be the reason for this and how can I resolve this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It had to be in uppercase:

```
callablestatement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.ARRAY,"DATES");
```

UPDATE: Oh, I found where I saw similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2787880/617455

Answer (score 1):

You defined 4 params:

```
connection.prepareCall("begin ? :=datefunc(?,?,?); end;");
```

but set only three of them:

```
callablestatement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.ARRAY,"dates");
callablestatement.setInt(2, param1);
callablestatement.setInt(3, param2);
```

Comment: That was a typo mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but, non of these solutions worked out for me.

I figured out some **Type** is missing in PL/SQL what I realised.

Comment: For example , request type should be needed CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE  "COMPANY_ARRAY"  is VARRAY(20) OF DATE                                      , So that DATES need to be created if it is not exist in database.