# Calling oracle pl sql stored procedure with IN parameter as Record type using Java

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, plsql

I want to call oracle pl/sql stored procedure  with IN parameter as Record type using Java.

I have tried JDBC connection,Hibernate and also JPA,

but i am getting one error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: invalid name pattern: APPS.cust_account_rec_type
```

Following is code snippet

//java code

```
try {
            OracleCallableStatement callStmt = null;
            String dbURL2 = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.3.12:1522:TEST";
            String username = "test";
            String password = "test";
            Connection conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL2, username,
                    password);
            // Stage values for each field in the Oracle record in an array
            Object[] javacustRec = new Object[101];
            javacustRec[74]="test1";
            javacustRec[99]="TCA_V2_API";
            Object[] javapersonRec = new Object[63];
            javapersonRec[1]="test2";
            javapersonRec[3]="test3";
            Object[] javacustProfileRec = new Object[108];
            if (conn2 != null) {
                logger.info("Connected with connection ");
                // Create descriptor for the Oracle Record type "cust_account_rec_type" required
                StructDescriptor recCustDesc = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("cust_account_rec_type", conn2);
                // Create descriptor for the Oracle Record type "cust_account_rec_type" required
                StructDescriptor recPersonDesc = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("person_rec_type", conn2);
                // Create descriptor for the Oracle Record type "cust_account_rec_type" required
                StructDescriptor recCustProfileDesc = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("customer_profile_rec_type", conn2);
                //create struct to send data as records to procedure parameter
                STRUCT custRecStruct = new STRUCT(recCustDesc, conn2, javacustRec);
              //create struct to send data as records to procedure parameter
                STRUCT personRecStruct = new STRUCT(recPersonDesc, conn2, javapersonRec);
              //create struct to send data as records to procedure parameter
                STRUCT custProfileRecStruct = new STRUCT(recCustProfileDesc, conn2, javacustProfileRec);
                String callProc = "{CALL HZ_CUST_ACCOUNT_V2PUB.CREATE_CUST_ACCOUNT(:p_create_profile_amt,:P_CUST_ACCOUNT_REC, :P_PERSON_REC, :P_CUSTOMER_PROFILE_REC, :p_create_profile_amt, :X_CUST_ACCOUNT_ID, :X_ACCOUNT_NUMBER, :X_PARTY_ID, :X_PARTY_NUMBER, :X_PROFILE_ID, :X_RETURN_STATUS, :X_MSG_COUNT, :X_MSG_DATA) }";
                // Create a Callable Statement
                callStmt = (OracleCallableStatement) conn2.prepareCall(callProc);
                callStmt.setObject("p_create_profile_amt", 'T');         // in parameter with default  value 'TRUE'
                callStmt.setSTRUCT("P_CUST_ACCOUNT_REC", custRecStruct);  //in cust_account_rec_type parameter to send IN RECORDS
                //callStmt.setObject("P_CUST_ACCOUNT_REC", custAccountRecType); //in parameter to send IN RECORDS                                                                       
                callStmt.setSTRUCT("P_PERSON_REC", personRecStruct);  //in cust_account_rec_type parameter to send IN RECORDS
                //callStmt.setObject("P_PERSON_REC", personRecType);                //in parameter to send IN RECORDS   
                callStmt.setSTRUCT("P_CUSTOMER_PROFILE_REC", custProfileRecStruct);  //in cust_account_rec_type parameter to send IN RECORDS
                //callStmt.setObject("P_CUSTOMER_PROFILE_REC",customerProfileRecType); //in parameter to send IN RECORDS    
                callStmt.setObject("p_init_msg_list", 'F');                 // in parameter with default  value 'FALSE'
                callStmt.registerOutParameter("X_CUST_ACCOUNT_ID",Types.NUMERIC );  //out parameter with NUMBER
                callStmt.registerOutParameter("X_ACCOUNT_NUMBER",Types.VARCHAR );    //out parameter with VARCHAR
                callStmt.registerOutParameter("X_PARTY_ID", Types.NUMERIC); //out parameter with NUMBER
                callStmt.registerOutParameter("X_PARTY_NUMBER", Types.VARCHAR);  //out parameter with VARCHAR
                callStmt.registerOutParameter("X_PROFILE_ID", Types.NUMERIC); //out parameter with NUMBER
                callStmt.registerOutParameter("X_RETURN_STATUS", Types.VARCHAR); //out parameter with VARCHAR
                callStmt.registerOutParameter("X_MSG_COUNT",Types.NUMERIC); //out parameter with NUMBER
                callStmt.registerOutParameter("X_MSG_DATA", Types.VARCHAR); //out parameter with VARCHAR
                callStmt.executeUpdate();

                //response after executing procedure
                clientContactRespose.setX_MSG_COUNT( callStmt.getInt("X_MSG_COUNT"));
                clientContactRespose.setX_MSG_DATA(callStmt.getString("X_MSG_DATA"));
                clientContactRespose.setX_PARTY_ID(callStmt.getInt("X_PARTY_ID"));
                clientContactRespose.setX_RETURN_STATUS(callStmt.getString("X_RETURN_STATUS"));
                clientContactRespose.setX_PROFILE_ID( callStmt.getInt("X_PROFILE_ID"));
                clientContactRespose.setX_PARTY_NUMBER(callStmt.getString("X_PARTY_NUMBER"));
                clientContactRespose.setX_CUST_ACCOUNT_ID(callStmt.getInt("X_CUST_ACCOUNT_ID"));

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.info("Error occurred at = "+e);
        }
```

Pl/Sql stored procedure As follows:

```
DECLARE
 P_CUST_ACCOUNT_REC     HZ_CUST_ACCOUNT_V2PUB.CUST_ACCOUNT_REC_TYPE;
 P_PERSON_REC           HZ_PARTY_V2PUB.PERSON_REC_TYPE;
 P_CUSTOMER_PROFILE_REC HZ_CUSTOMER_PROFILE_V2PUB.CUSTOMER_PROFILE_REC_TYPE;
 X_CUST_ACCOUNT_ID      NUMBER;
 X_ACCOUNT_NUMBER       VARCHAR2(2000);
 X_PARTY_ID             NUMBER;
 X_PARTY_NUMBER         VARCHAR2(2000);
 X_PROFILE_ID           NUMBER;
 X_RETURN_STATUS        VARCHAR2(2000);
 X_MSG_COUNT            NUMBER;
 X_MSG_DATA             VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
 FND_CLIENT_INFO.SET_ORG_CONTEXT('1057');
 P_CUST_ACCOUNT_REC.ACCOUNT_NAME      := 'test1';
 P_CUST_ACCOUNT_REC.CREATED_BY_MODULE := 'TCA_V2_API';
 P_PERSON_REC.PERSON_FIRST_NAME       := 'test2';
 P_PERSON_REC.PERSON_LAST_NAME        := 'test3';
 HZ_CUST_ACCOUNT_V2PUB.CREATE_CUST_ACCOUNT('T', P_CUST_ACCOUNT_REC, P_PERSON_REC, P_CUSTOMER_PROFILE_REC, 'F', X_CUST_ACCOUNT_ID, X_ACCOUNT_NUMBER, X_PARTY_ID, X_PARTY_NUMBER, X_PROFILE_ID, X_RETURN_STATUS, X_MSG_COUNT, X_MSG_DATA);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('x_return_status = ' || SUBSTR(X_RETURN_STATUS, 1, 255));
 IF X_MSG_COUNT > 1 THEN
  FOR I IN 1 .. X_MSG_COUNT LOOP
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I || '. ' ||
                        SUBSTR(FND_MSG_PUB.GET(P_ENCODED => FND_API.G_FALSE), 1, 255));
  END LOOP;
 END IF;
END;
```

Note-cust_account_rec_type Is Record .(Not Object).
and I don't want to change my stored procedure.

```
TYPE cust_account_rec_type IS RECORD (
    cust_account_id                         NUMBER,
    account_number                          VARCHAR2(30),
    attribute_category                      VARCHAR2(30),
    attribute1                              VARCHAR2(150),
    attribute2                              VARCHAR2(150),
    attribute3                              VARCHAR2(150),
    attribute4                              VARCHAR2(150)
}
```

Your help is appreciable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [invalid name pattern when trying to pass custom oracle type object mapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589155/invalid-name-pattern-when-trying-to-pass-custom-oracle-type-object-mapping)

Comment: not sure but you may need to user oracle database object instead on records; oracle object can be mapped to java.

Comment: I thins its access issue with the created record. can you try creating public synonym for the type and give execute privilege.

Comment: Thank you for answer but I am using custom oracle type is **RECORD** not **OBJECT**. Oracle **RECORD** can not be mapped to java. I appreciate if you provide me any other solution